# How can I read this java.beans.XMLDecoder with C# the problem are to read the java.util.TreeMap

Tags: c#

Xml File:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <java version="1.8.0_121" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
     <object class="jp.mimaki.p2p.cmn.properties.PropPositions_Card_300_420">
      <void property="_VERSION">
       <string>6.09</string>
      </void>
      <void property="basePicturePitchH">
       <double>60.0</double>
      </void>
      <void property="basePicturePitchW">
       <double>48.0</double>
      </void>
      <void property="basePictureSizeH">
       <double>40.0</double>
      </void>
      <void property="basePictureSizeW">
       <double>40.0</double>
      </void>
      <void property="direction">
       <int>0</int>
      </void>
      <void property="firstOriginH">
       <double>9.55</double>
      </void>
      <void property="firstOriginW">
       <double>9.7</double>
      </void>
      <void property="fittedScale">
       <boolean>false</boolean>
      </void>
      <void property="fixedScale">
       <boolean>true</boolean>
      </void>
      <void property="jigDeskew">
       <double>0.0</double>
      </void>
      <void property="jigOriginH">
       <double>0.37</double>
      </void>
      <void property="jigOriginW">
       <double>1.3</double>
      </void>
      <void property="jigSizeH">
       <double>420.0</double>
      </void>
      <void property="jigSizeW">
       <double>297.0</double>
      </void>
      <void property="mobilePhoneJigAngle">
       <float>0.0</float>
      </void>
      <void property="modilePhoneJigHeight">
       <float>0.0</float>
      </void>
      <void property="pdfLineColor">
       <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.color.Colors">
        <void property="colorSpace">
         <int>9</int>
        </void>
        <void property="k">
         <float>1.0</float>
        </void>
       </object>
      </void>
      <void property="pdfLineOffset">
       <double>0.35277777910232544</double>
      </void>
      <void property="pdfLineOffsetMode">
       <int>1</int>
      </void>
      <void property="pdfLineWidth">
       <int>1</int>
      </void>
      <void property="pictureCountsH">
       <int>7</int>
      </void>
      <void property="pictureCountsW">
       <int>6</int>
      </void>
      <void property="pictureRectangles">
       <object class="java.util.TreeMap">
        <void method="put">
         <string>001_001</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect"/>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>001_002</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>60.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>001_003</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>120.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>001_004</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.1</double>
          </void>
          <void property="deltaY">
           <double>0.05</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>180.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>001_005</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.15</double>
          </void>
          <void property="deltaY">
           <double>0.08</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>240.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>001_006</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.2</double>
          </void>
          <void property="deltaY">
           <double>0.05</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>300.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>001_007</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.25</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>360.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>002_001</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>48.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>002_002</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>60.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>48.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>002_003</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>120.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>48.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>002_004</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.15</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>180.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>48.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>002_005</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.1</double>
          </void>
          <void property="deltaY">
           <double>0.05</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>240.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>48.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>002_006</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.2</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>300.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>48.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>002_007</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.3</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>360.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>48.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>003_001</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>96.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>003_002</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>60.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>96.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>003_003</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.1</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>120.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>96.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>003_004</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.1</double>
          </void>
          <void property="deltaY">
           <double>0.05</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>180.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>96.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>003_005</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.15</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>240.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>96.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>003_006</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.2</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>300.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>96.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>003_007</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.28</double>
          </void>
          <void property="deltaY">
           <double>-0.05</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>360.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>96.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>004_001</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>144.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>004_002</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.13</double>
          </void>
          <void property="deltaY">
           <double>-0.13</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>60.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>144.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>004_003</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.2</double>
          </void>
          <void property="deltaY">
           <double>-0.05</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>120.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>144.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>004_004</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.2</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>180.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>144.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>004_005</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.3</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>240.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>144.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>004_006</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.3</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>300.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>144.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>004_007</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.38</double>
          </void>
          <void property="deltaY">
           <double>-0.1</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>360.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>144.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>005_001</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>192.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>005_002</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.15</double>
          </void>
          <void property="deltaY">
           <double>-0.15</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>60.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>192.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>005_003</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.2</double>
          </void>
          <void property="deltaY">
           <double>-0.1</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>120.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>192.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>005_004</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.33</double>
          </void>
          <void property="deltaY">
           <double>-0.05</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>180.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>192.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>005_005</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.35</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>240.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>192.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>005_006</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.35</double>
          </void>
          <void property="deltaY">
           <double>-0.05</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>300.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>192.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>005_007</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.43</double>
          </void>
          <void property="deltaY">
           <double>-0.15</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>360.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>192.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>006_001</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.1</double>
          </void>
          <void property="deltaY">
           <double>-0.28</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>240.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>006_002</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.18</double>
          </void>
          <void property="deltaY">
           <double>-0.15</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>60.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>240.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>006_003</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.25</double>
          </void>
          <void property="deltaY">
           <double>-0.25</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>120.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>240.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>006_004</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.3</double>
          </void>
          <void property="deltaY">
           <double>-0.1</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>180.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>240.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>006_005</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.4</double>
          </void>
          <void property="deltaY">
           <double>-0.05</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>240.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>240.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>006_006</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.43</double>
          </void>
          <void property="deltaY">
           <double>-0.08</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>300.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>240.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
         <string>006_007</string>
         <object class="jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect">
          <void property="deltaX">
           <double>0.4</double>
          </void>
          <void property="deltaY">
           <double>-0.2</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetH">
           <double>360.0</double>
          </void>
          <void property="offsetW">
           <double>240.0</double>
          </void>
         </object>
        </void>
       </object>
      </void>
      <void property="positioningPolicy">
       <int>14</int>
      </void>
      <void property="printerNo">
       <int>1</int>
      </void>
      <void property="removable">
       <boolean>true</boolean>
      </void>
      <void property="useMobilePhoneJig">
       <boolean>false</boolean>
      </void>
      <void property="wholeSizeH">
       <double>420.0</double>
      </void>
      <void property="wholeSizeW">
       <double>300.0</double>
      </void>
     </object>
    </java>
```

I can read this code with the first level

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Temp\M0592.ARY.xml");     //@"C:\TempPrint2\test.xml"); 

var nodesList = doc.Root.Descendants("void");

Dictionary<string, string> xmlValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (XElement element in nodesList)
{
    if (element.ToString().Contains("property"))
    {
        xmlValues.Add(element.Attribute("property").Value, element.Value);
    }
}

string color = xmlValues["pdfLineColor"];
string careof = xmlValues["pdfLineOffset"];
string districtName = xmlValues["pdfLineColor"];
```

I can read the second level with this, only I see not the discription

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
// doc.Load(@"C:\Temp\test4.xml");
doc.Load(@"C:\Temp\M0592.ARY.xml");

//string a = @"/java/object[@class='java.util.TreeMap']/void/object[@class='jp.mimaki.cmn.math.AdjustableRect']";
string a = @"/java/object/void/object/void/object/void";

string b = @"/java/object/void";

XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes(b);

List<PersonDetail> personList = new List<PersonDetail>();

foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    if (node.ChildNodes != null && node.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
    {
        PersonDetail person = new PersonDetail();

        person.property = node.ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
                        
        personList.Add(person);
    }
}

string C1 = personList.Count.ToString();

GridView1.DataSource = personList;
```

How can I read all void in to a table or json file
I can only read the after the void the amount?